help add curve extra objects
help me please
I don't have an addon add curve extra objects
I reinstalled blender
wrote differently - starting with extra
but still it is not in the search, what to do with it ТТ

Hello and welcome. Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/321748/142292

Thank you very much, happiness, goodness and health!
